# nam (Network animation) console is not comming in ns2

Tags: ns2

I have successfully installed ns2 in Ubuntu 16 version but my nam console is not appearing. I have tried direct accessing nam folder but I am getting an error that "dictionary not found".

Comment: Unknown ns2 version : Please edit your question to include version of ns-allinone-2 .

Answer (score 1):

The Ubuntu `nam` packages cannot be used, the two year old bug report is here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nam/+bug/1376970

You can download a package for your OS, select i386 for a 32bits OS, or amd64 for 64bits :

```
nam_1.15-10-ubuntu14_amd64.deb
```

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNdmxzSmRzaVRWb28/view?usp=sharing

```
nam_1.15-10_i386.deb
```

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNUkx0LVU1NnFVQTA/view?usp=sharing

Install : `cd Downloads/` ... and ... `sudo gdebi ./[package].deb`

Edit: Ubuntu 18.04 and later Ubuntu versions:

```
sudo apt install Downloads/[package].deb
```